# Install Bash + openSSH on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, ssh, bash, windows-server-2012

I had to create a Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012.
Now I want to connect to it via OpenSSH and Bash, installing OpenSSH is successful, however when I connect to the server via `ssh Administrator@<ip>` I can only use the Windows Powershell. Is it possible to install a bash (like git bash or cygwin) and to connect via ssh directly to this shell ?

Comment: 2012 foundation ?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 Standart 64-bit (German)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Cygwin, then use Cygwin, right?  A big limitation with my instructions is that it's for a single user at a time, SSH isn't running as a service.  Hopefully someone can provide an answer to get it working as a service.

Download the installer **setup-x86-64.exe** and run it.

You need these packages:

- cygrunsrv
- openssh
- openssl
- rsync
- xinit
- xorg-docs
- xorg-server

After Cygwin is installed, run the "Cygwin64 Terminal" as Administrator.

```
ssh-host-config
```

> Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) **yes**
>
> new local account 'sshd'? (yes/no) **yes**
>
> Do you want to install sshd as a service? (Say "no" if it is already installed as a service) (yes/no) **no**

Give your user ownership of their SSH directory:

```
chown username /var/empty /etc/ssh*
```

Edit the sshd configuration file:

```
vi /etc/sshd_config
```

Allow the SSH environment file to be used for non-interactive sessions:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

You need a login script to start sshd every time, I lazily created sshd.bat and copied it to **shell:common startup**

```
@echo off

REM # Start SSH server, as a regular process.  Use /var/log/sshd.log instead of
REM # Windows Event Log
C:\cygwin64\bin\run -p C:\cygwin64\bin /usr/sbin/sshd -D -E /var/log/sshd.log
```

Improvements welcome!

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide

The link above says this is just available on latest Windows 10 version:

**Your PC must be running a 64-bit version of Windows 10 Anniversary Update build 14393 or later**